# Material design custom icon color

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm using material design theme for my toolbar and I'm using a custom instagram icon on one of the tabs. The problem is instead of an icon, only black or white shape of it is being displayed. How do I fix it?
Thank you.

[View from different tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKsGW.png)

[View from instagram tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RscpA.png)

Here's my icon XML:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="512dp"
android:height="512dp"
android:viewportWidth="512"
android:viewportHeight="512">
<path
    android:fillColor="#834fe2"
    android:pathData="M15 0H497A15 15 0 0 1 512 15V497A15 15 0 0 1 497 512H15A15 15 0 0 1 0 497V15A15 15 0 0 1 15 0Z" />
<path
    android:pathData="M186 108H326A78 78 0 0 1 404 186V326A78 78 0 0 1 326 404H186A78 78 0 0 1 108 326V186A78 78 0 0 1 186 108Z"
    android:strokeWidth="29"
    android:strokeColor="#fbfbfb" />
<path
    android:pathData="M325 256A69 69 0 0 1 187 256A69 69 0 0 1 325 256Z"
    android:strokeWidth="29"
    android:strokeColor="#fbfbfb" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#fbfbfb"
    android:pathData="M362 169A19 19 0 0 1 324 169A19 19 0 0 1 362 169Z" />
```

**Here's my styles value:**

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Here's my colors value:**

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#834fe2</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fbfbfb</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#52b7f8</color>
<color name="backgroundFragment">#fbfbfb</color>
```

Comment: In your case, the icon is tinted white when selected and black when unselected. That means every non-transparent pixel will be that color. Use a shape instead of a colorful image (e.g. the inverse of [this](https://seeklogo.com/vector-logo/306458/instagram)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the vector to remove the unnecessary background. The TabLayout tints the icons depending on the selection state. Your image contained a non-transparent background that was getting tinted together with the image.

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">

    <path
        android:pathData="M186 108H326A78 78 0 0 1 404 186V326A78 78 0 0 1 326 404H186A78 78 0 0 1 108 326V186A78 78 0 0 1 186 108Z"
        android:strokeWidth="29"
        android:strokeColor="#fbfbfb" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M325 256A69 69 0 0 1 187 256A69 69 0 0 1 325 256Z"
        android:strokeWidth="29"
        android:strokeColor="#fbfbfb" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#fbfbfb"
        android:pathData="M362 169A19 19 0 0 1 324 169A19 19 0 0 1 362 169Z" />
</vector>
```